# How to connect azure queue storage and azure blob storage with celery by sas

Tags: celery, azure-storage, sas-token

I have this kind of code:

```
app = Celery('myapp', broker='azurestoragequeues://:{sas_token}@{url}', backend='azureblockblob://:{another_sas_token}@{another_url}')
```

When I run celery -A myapp, I got this error

> 'azure.storage.queue._shared.authentication.AzureSigningError:
> Incorrect padding'

I test the tokens on azure storage explorer and they work fine. I can access the storage of given token. The doc of celery only show how to build CELERY_BROKER_URL by account access key and name. But I only have sas token.